# cmd.exe launched from another cmd.exe

Tags: windows, bash, cmd.exe, cygwin, bash-scripting

I'm doing a script that I start with `bash.exe` from Cygwin on Windows:

```
C:\bash.exe my_script.sh
```

It changes my Python Virtual Env depending of some conditions. For those who know Virtualenv, I need to use "workon.bat" and the only way I know to execute a batch script is the following one:

```
...
cmd /K "workon.bat" "$required_venv"
...
```

It works but I'm now in a new `cmd.exe` instance launched from the previous one. Proof : Typing `exit` bring me back to it :

```
C:\bash.exe my_script.sh  *ENTER*
(venv) C:\
(venv) C:\exit            *ENTER*
C:\
```

In fact, each time I will launch that script I will be in a new instance :

```
cmd.exe
    cmd.exe
        cmd.exe
           cmd.exe
               ...
```

How to solve that annoying recursive situation ? One solution could be to detect that I'm in a cmd launched into another one and exit. I would be ideal to execute the batch workon.bat while remaining inside the cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
cmd /K "workon.bat" "$required_venv"
```

Use

```
cmd /C "workon.bat" "$required_venv"
```

As it will close the new shell after running the batch file, from `cmd /?`

```
/c  Carries out the command specified by String and then stops.
/k  Carries out the command specified by String and continues.
```

Comment: This doens't work unfortunatly because if it close the new shell, it close also the the virtual venv, right ? : (

Comment: using /c doesn't keep the virtualenv :/

Answer (score 0):

@matzeri is wrong about `cmd /C` as it will also close the virtualenv which is unexpected. I think that doing that job on Windows using Cygwin, Bash and script-shell was a bad idea, I ended up by doing a batch file instead.